# BIOS keyboard buffer

Tags: assembly, nasm, bare-metal

I decided to do some fun with assembly and bare-metal to increase my programming skills for operating system development. So I decided to make game similar to 'space invaders'.

I have made some working code, but the problem comes with Interrupt 0x16 AH=0x01.
From [Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm) we can read that this interrupt does NOT clear keyboard buffer. Because of that after clicking any control key once, my game believe that this key is kept pressed, and other key press are ignored, causing my ship to go infinity into one direction.

I have tried using AH=0x00 and it worked perfectly, however this would stop the game until any key is pressed, and I do not want that because I wont be able to update enemies position without waiting for user input.

I concider it to be problem with int 0x16 AH=0x01 and that the buffer is not cleared, however it may be something with either my `lup` or with call `keyPressControl`.

By the way I am using bochs to test my code and compiling my code with nasm

This is my code:

```
org 0x7C00
bits 16

xor ax,ax
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax

mov bx,0x8000
cli
mov ss,bx
mov sp,ax
sti

cld
clc

;clear 0x7E00 so we can check is code loaded later
xor ah,ah
mov BYTE [0x7E00], AH

;this code suppose to load game into memory
mov ah,0x2
mov al,0x4
xor ch,ch
mov cl,0x2
xor dh,dh
xor bx,bx
mov es,bx
mov bx,0x7E00
int 0x13
;code above should load code just above bootloader
;check if code is loaded
mov AH,[0x7E00]
cmp AH,0x0
je error

;Use normal jumpbecause bochs doesnt support Far Jumps (code often crashes)
jmp 0x7E00
;if cpu dont jump somehow then it will execute error and then hopefully halt
error:
    ;fill the screen with red color - the screen is supposed to run in graphics mode 0x2
    mov ah,0x40
    mov al,' '
    cld
    mov bx,0xb800
    mov es,bx
    xor bx,bx
    mov di,bx
    mov cx,0x0FA0
    rep stosw
    stosw

cli
hlt

times 0x1FE - ($ - $$) db 0x0

db 0x55
db 0xAA


;==============================
;game code
;==============================

;the game is designed to run in 16 bit real mode
;hide text mode cursor
mov ah,0x1
mov cx,0x2607
int 0x10
;show 'menu'
call clearTextModeScr
xor ax,ax
mov DS,AX
mov AX,GameName
mov SI,AX
xor AL,AL
mov bl,0x10
call printInTextMode
mov AX,TextInfo01
mov si,ax
mov al,0x6
call printInTextMode
mov AX,TextInfo02
mov si,ax
mov al,0x7
call printInTextMode
mov AX,TextInfo03
mov si,ax
mov al,0x8
call printInTextMode
mov AX,TextInfo04
mov si,ax
mov al,0x9
call printInTextMode
mov AX,TextInfo05
mov si,ax
mov al,0xA
call printInTextMode
mov AX,TextInfo06
mov si,ax
mov al,0xB
call printInTextMode
mov AX,TextInfo07
mov si,ax
mov al,0x17
call printInTextMode

;wait for x to start the game
mov bl,'x'
call waitForKeyPress
;init 0x13 graphics mode
call initGraphicsMode

lup:
    ;draw ship
    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov si,ship
    mov bx, [shipPosX]
    mov al, [shipPosY]
    call DrawPicture

    call KeyPressControl
    jmp lup
cli
hlt
;game functions


;this function will update new location of ship on screen according to player keypress
;this function will be using BIOS buffer from keyboard to not suspend the game
KeyPressControl:
    pusha
    pushf
    mov ah,0x1
    int 0x16
    jz .end
    cmp al,'a' ;left
    je .left
    cmp al,'d' ;right
    je .right
    cmp al,'s' ;backwards
    je .backwards
    cmp al,'w' ;forwards
    je .forwards
    jmp .end
    .left:
        cmp WORD [shipPosX], 0x00
        je .end
        dec WORD [shipPosX]
        jmp .end
    .right:
        cmp WORD [shipPosX], 0x12D
        je .end
        inc WORD [shipPosX]
        jmp .end
    .backwards:
        cmp BYTE [shipPosY], 0xA9
        je .end
        inc BYTE [shipPosY]
        jmp .end
    .forwards:
        cmp BYTE [shipPosY], 0x00
        je .end
        dec BYTE [shipPosY]
        jmp .end
    .end:
        popf
        popa
        ret

;this function winn wait till right key is pressed
;bl - ASCII key

;All registers and flags should be left the same
waitForKeyPress:
    pusha
    pushf
    .loop:
        xor ah,ah
        int 0x16
        cmp al,bl
        jne .loop
    popf
    popa
    ret


;this function will clear text mode screen to white text with black background

;All registers should be left the same
clearTextModeScr:
    pusha
    mov ah,0x0F
    mov al,' '
    cld
    mov bx,0xb800
    mov es,bx
    xor bx,bx
    mov di,bx
    mov cx,0x0FA0
    rep stosw
    stosw
    popa
    ret

;holy shit

;this function will generate pseudo random value
; Following registers will be changed:
;   AX - random generated number
random:
    push DX
    push BX
    ;multiplier is get by Read Time Stamp
    RDTSC
    mov BX,AX
    mov AX,[randomSeed]
    mul BX
    add ax,0xB7FF
    and ax,0x7FFF
    ;ax is random number
    mov WORD [randomSeed], ax
    pop BX
    pop DX
    ret



;this function will draw image on screen
;DS:SI - address of the picture start
;AL - Y coordinate (height)
;BX - X coordinate (width)

;Note that this funciton wont check for 0x13 graphics mode
DrawPicture:
    pusha
    mov cx,0x140
    mul cx
    add AX,BX
    ;AX is now offset on the screen
    mov bx,0xA000
    mov es,bx
    mov di,ax
    ;memory location of screen is now written in ES:DI
    ;now we need to get the size of picture
    lodsw ;get WORD into AX
    ;AL - X size
    ;AH - Y size
    xor cx,cx
    mov CL,AL
    cld
    .loopY:
        push ax
        push es
        push di
        push cx
        .loopX:
            lodsb
            stosb
            loop .loopX
        pop cx
        pop di
        pop es
        mov ax,0x140
        add di,ax
        pop ax
        dec ah
        cmp ah,0x0
        jne .loopY
    popa
    ret

;this function will draw box on screen
;AL - Y coordinate (height)
;BX - X coordinate (width)
;CL - X size
;DL - colour
;DH - Y size

;All registers should be left the same
DrawBox:
    pusha
    ;calculate the start point in memory
    ;multiply Y coordinate by 0x140 (width of each Y line)
    push bx
    mov bx,0x140
    mul bx
    pop bx
    ;add X
    add AX,BX
    ;AX is now offset on the screen
    mov bx,0xA000
    mov es,bx
    mov di,ax
    cld
    xor CH,CH
    .loopY:
        push es
        push di
        push cx
        ;.loopX will be repeated `CL` times
        .loopX:
            stosb
            loop .loopX
        pop cx
        pop di
        pop es
        mov ax,0x140
        add di,ax
        ;decrease dh
        dec dh
        ;repeat loop `DH` times
        cmp dh,0x0
        jne .loopY
    popa
    ret

;this function will return length of string in CX
;DS:SI - address of the text

; Following registers will be changed
;   DS:SI   - location of last byte of the string in memory
;   CX      - length of the string
getStringLenght:
    push ax
    xor cx,cx
    .loop:
        lodsb
        ;check is it terminate character
        cmp al,'#'
        ;if yes then finish
        je .end
        ;increase CX (length) and execute loop again
        inc cx
        jmp .loop
    .end:
        pop ax
        ret


;this function will not check is text mode set
;DS:SI - address of the text
;AL - Y coordinate (start)
;BL - X coordinate (start)

;text should be terminated with # sign 
;
;All registers and flags should be left the same
printInTextMode:
    pusha
    pushf
    push bx
    mov bl,0x50
    mul bl
    pop bx
    xor bh,bh
    add ax,bx
    mov bx,0x2
    mul bx
    mov di,ax
    mov bx,0xb800
    mov es,bx
    mov ah,0x0F ;white colour on black background
    cld
    .loop:
        lodsb
        cmp al,'#'
        je .end
        stosw
        jmp .loop
    .end:
        popf
        popa
        ret

SYSerror:
    ;set text mode graphics
    call initTextMode
    ;if text mode graphics could not be set, then halt the CPU straight away
    jc .fullerror
    ;fill the screen with red color
    mov ah,0x40
    mov al,' '
    cld
    mov bx,0xb800
    mov es,bx
    xor bx,bx
    mov di,bx
    mov cx,0x0FA0
    rep stosw
    stosw
    ;halt the CPU
    .fullerror:
        cli
        hlt

;if error occured then carry flag will be set
;if function runned properly then carry flag will be cleared
;
;All registers should be left the same
initTextMode:
    pusha
    ;setgup graphics mode 0x02
    xor ah,ah
    mov al,0x2
    int 0x10
    ;get graphics mode
    mov ah,0x0F
    int 0x10
    ;check if the graphics mode is actually 0x02
    cmp al,0x02
    jne .err
    ;clear carry flag and return
    popa
    clc
    ret
    ;error set carry flag and return
    .err:
        popa
        stc
        ret


;if error occured then carry flag will be set
;if function runned properly then carry flag will be cleared
;
;All registers should be left the same
initGraphicsMode:
    pusha
    ;setup mode 0x13
    xor ah,ah
    mov al,0x13
    int 0x10
    ;get graphics mode
    mov ah,0x0F
    int 0x10
    ;check if the graphics mode is actually 0x13
    cmp al,0x13
    jne .err
    popa
    clc
    ret
    .err:
        popa
        stc
        ret


cli
hlt
;game data
;'variables'

randomSeed dw 0xBEAF
shipPosX dw 0x0000
shipPosY db 0x00


;Game texts
GameName db 'Lasers Lasers Lasers... And Even More Lasers#'
TextInfo01 db 'Controls:#'
TextInfo02 db 'A - Left#'
TextInfo03 db 'D - Right#'
TextInfo04 db 'W - Forward#'
TextInfo05 db 'S - Backward#'
TextInfo06 db 'Q - Weapon#'
TextInfo07 db 'Press x to begin game#'

;Game Pictures... YES PICTURES


;structure of pictures
;First WORD is size of picture. It is in following format

;ship 17x29 (0x11 * 0x1D) (1D is height, 11 is width)

ship:
    dw 0x1F13
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x2A, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x2A, 0x29, 0x29, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x2A, 0x29, 0x29, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x2A, 0x29, 0x29, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x29, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x1E, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x1E, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x29, 0x1E, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x29, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x29, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x29, 0x29, 0x1E, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x29, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x29, 0x29, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00



times 0x1000 - ($ - $$) db 0x0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is a way of checking for keypresses and removing them from the buffer without waiting?

Just use int 0x16/AH=01 to check for a key and *if a keypress is in the buffer* use int 0x16/AH=00 to clear it from the buffer. Your detection of keys will be limited by key repeat rate and delay, however.

In practice, most (old...) games trapped int 9 (I think it was) to detect key press/release, and then queried the keyboard controller directly (using port I/O), rather than using the BIOS routines - which are not really designed with games in mind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988886/scan-the-keyboard-to-obtain-scan-codes